# Installing Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, installation

I just downloaded Xamarin for Visual Studio, but since installing Xamarin and restarting my computer, I cannot get it to appear in VS 2013. If Xamarin has installed properly generally you can click Tools -> Options and Xamarin should appear on the menu list.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Do you have installed the latest update for VS2013?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Professional or above with Update 2 is recommended. You should also see three items at the top of the tools menu. Also check that Xamarin Studio itself is running properly.